# How to use wait() and notify() in Runnable inside Handler properly?

Tags: android, service, handler, runnable

I have find any similar question about my problem a couple hours ago, but i'm not find it yet,

I want to upload data using `Service` with `Handler` and `Runnable` but I facing the problem that `handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, interval)` is re-run when the block code inside `run()` is not yet finish, all i know is to use `wait() and notify()` but i don't know where should i put these `methods`

my Service code looks like:

```
public class ServiceUploadData extends Service {
  Handler handler = new Handler();
  private Runnable periodicUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      Log.v(TAG, "Service Upload Data Running Now");
      //check localDB and send the data if exist
      handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
  };

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
  {
    Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    context = this;
    handler.post(periodicUpdate);
    return START_STICKY;
  }
  //any @Override
}
```

anyone can help me out?

Comment: May I ask a stupid question: is onStartCommand called multiple times?

Comment: No. onStartCommand just called once, but the interval not sync